# TypeError on beautifulsoup file open

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I don't see why I'm getting an error on this. Could someone nice explain to me what's happening? I tried to follow some other examples, but apparently I have failed :P

```
import BeautifulSoup as bs

def readHTML():
    soup = bs("stats.html")
    print(soup.prettify())
```

Why am I getting a type error?

```
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Comment: Use `soup = bs.BeautifulSOAP("stats.html")`what version of BeautifulSoup are you using? You should update to bs4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to utilize the class "BeautifulSoup" that is within the module

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as bs

def readHTML():   
    soup = bs("stats.html")
    print(soup.prettify())
```

Comment: Or he could just do soup = bs.BeautifulSoup("stats.html")